# How do I find a range for p such that this series converges?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I proved the series below diverges for any p<0 by using the fact that

$$\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\frac{1}{\left(\ln\:n\right)^p}\right)=+\infty,\text{ if }p<0$$

But can't find any range in which this series:
$$\sum _{n=2}^{\infty }\:\frac{1}{\left(\ln\:n\right)^p}$$
converges.

Comment: This never converges. For $p >0$, you could show that $\log(n)^p <n$ for sufficiently large $p$, thus the series always diverges by comparison test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fixed $p >0$ and large enough $n$, $\ln{n} < n^{1/p}$. Thus $\frac{1}{(n^{1/p})^p} < \frac{1}{(\ln{n})^p}$ for large $n$.  We know $\sum{\frac{1}{n}}$ diverges, and then by the comparison test, $\sum{\frac{1}{(\ln{n})^p}}$ also diverges.

To show $\ln{n} < n^{1/p}$ for large $n$, we can show $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln{n}}{n^{1/p}} = 0$ with one application of L'Hospital's Rule.